# How to hide other opened lists when click on the current list heading in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML -

```
<div id="new_results">
    <div class="new_result">
        <div class="new_result_header"><h3>Acura ILX</h3></div>
        <div class="new_trim_dropdown"><p>Available Trims - <span>3</span></p>
            <ul class="new_trim_values">
            <li>4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl 5A) </li>
            <li>4dr Sedan w/Premium Package (2.4L 4cyl 6M)</li>
            <li>44dr Sedan w/Premium Package (2.0L 4cyl 5A)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="new_result">
        <div class="new_result_header"><h3>Acura ILX Hybrid</h3></div>
        <div class="new_trim_dropdown"><p>Available Trims - <span>3</span></p>
            <ul class="new_trim_values">
            <li>4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl 5A) </li>
            <li>4dr Sedan w/Premium Package (2.4L 4cyl 6M)</li>
            <li>44dr Sedan w/Premium Package (2.0L 4cyl 5A)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="new_result">
        <div class="new_result_header"><h3>Acura MDX</h3></div>
        <div class="new_trim_dropdown"><p>Available Trims - <span>3</span></p>
            <ul class="new_trim_values">
            <li>4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl 5A) </li>
            <li>4dr Sedan w/Premium Package (2.4L 4cyl 6M)</li>
            <li>44dr Sedan w/Premium Package (2.0L 4cyl 5A)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.new_result
{
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
#new_results .new_trim_values
{
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".new_trim_dropdown", function(event){
    if($(event.target).is($(this).children()))
    {
        $(this).children('.new_trim_values').toggle();
        $(this).parents(".new_result").siblings(".new_result").children('.new_trim_values').hide();
    }

});
</script>
```

Now at start all list items are hidden. When i click on "Available Trims - 3" then its corresponding list items will be toggled i.e. show and hide effect. Its already happening. But if I click on other hidden list items' heading - Available Trims - 3 then any previous or next shown list items should be hidden. I am using the second line code in jquery but its not working for me. What's wrong at there. Plz correct it. Thanks.

DEMO at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/php123/9TSV9/)

**EDIT -**

Also i want to hide the other or current opened list if someone clicks off it - if we click any part of document other than the current opened list. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.children()` only go down one level in the DOM tree.

In your case, `.new_trim_values` is the descendant of `.new_result` hence you need to use **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** instead of `.children()`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".new_trim_dropdown", function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).is($(this).children())) {
        $(this).children('.new_trim_values').toggle();
        $(this).parents(".new_result").siblings(".new_result").find('.new_trim_values').hide();
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TSV9/1/)**

Comment: Thanks bro. That worked really very well. Yes you are right the element with class `".new_trim_values"` is the descendant of `".new_result"` and not a direct child.

Answer (score 1):

I find more practical to hide all first and show selected after that:

```
$(document).on("click", ".new_trim_dropdown", function(event){
    if($(event.target).is($(this).children()))
    {
        $('.new_trim_values').hide();
        $(this).children('.new_trim_values').toggle();
    }
});
```